# How To Add Second ProgressBar Android ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

Friends;

How To Set ProgressDialog Second Progress Bar Like Below Images.

[image]

thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot you show is not a ProgressDialog, it is just a Dialog with a custom layout. 
What you need, in order to show a dialog like the one in your picture is:

1. A custom layout defining two ProgressBars, one below the other.
2. Create a Dialog and call yourDialog.setContentView(R.id.yourCustomLayout)
3. That's it, that's all you need

I would like to call your attention to the fact that you can also show the second progress in the same ProgressBar as the first, by using yourProgressBar.setSecondaryProgress(progressValue).

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in assuming that this is a layout issue? You want to have that second progress below the box that it is currently in?

If that's the case, use a relative layout and in the layout xml add this line to the progess bar:

```
android:layout_below="...."
```

In the quotation marks enter the id of the box that they are currently in.