# How to set Customized Progress Bars in Android

Tags: android

How to set Customized Progress Bars.

I want to show **two progress Bars**

When i have to download 200 files.

1) **First Progress Bar** shows **overall downloading status**.How many files are downloaded.

2) **Second Bar** Shows what percentage of **current file downloading**.

Comment: Have a look at this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704940/how-to-add-second-progressbar-android-progressdialog

Comment: Your question isn't really phrased clearly: what is it your asking exactly? In other words: what part do you need help with, and what do you have so far?

Comment: My Question is , I have to download more than one files(assume 200). Then i have to show progress dialogs as                              1)First shows That 4/200 files downloaded or 5/200 downloading.      2)Second shows 5th file downloading status in percentage(i.e. 40% downloading)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer to change the progress bar's current value, like 1%, 2%, 3% etc. Consider `sendmessage change view`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved, what you are asking. i can give you way to implement:

---

1. Create your custom progressbar extending Progress bar
2. Override onDraw method
3. Draw progress bar with downloaded amount or
   customProgessBar.setProgress('downloaded value');
4. Draw text at right side of progress bar with percent value (You have
   to create this with onDraw method)

Comment: Your question is now unclear to me, do u need both thing in simple progress bar, or do u want to do this with two seperate progress bar?